# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS how to set all hdd drives always on - prevent from sleeping or spin down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, sleep, ubuntu-22.04

On a pretty large system with 1000+ hdd drives I have a problem where hdd drives are going to **sleep | spinning down** (if you find it more accurate).

The system is running on **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**, as stated in title, but I think it is a more general question to linux.

In the server I have a **mix of SATA and SAS** drives, connected through **HBA's and JBOD's** - I don't think the capacity will matter here.

**So how can I prevent these drives from spinning down?**

Finding out how to do this **per drive** is obviously my **goal**, but maybe there is a **global system wide solution**?

I've already tried `sudo hdparm -S 254 /dev/sdXX` or with 0, but I'am getting errors in all these cases like this:

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 01 cf 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I would be more than glad, if anyone from the superuser community, could guide me towards the proper solution.

Comment: A proper solution?  Nah.. I don't have one of those; however, I have (in the past) written stupid "touch" services to touch the drive parameters every so often to keep them from spinning down for both Linux and Windows.  I am interested to hear what the real solution is.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas for now I am thinking of using the same approach. BTW what command have you used? I mean did you tried to fetch|read some drive parameters or write new file using touch and deleted it afterwards repeatedly with some time interval?

Comment: In my "stupid but worked solution" .. I used 'c'.  I think I simply opened and closed the drive with something like `if ((fd = open("/dev/hda", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) { close(fd) };}`  This is pseudo-code.. I think I did something like this but it has been a while.